# How to restrict more than two digits after a dot using Regex and DocumentFilter?

Tags: java, regex, swing, documentfilter

I am trying to make some JTextFields to validate only double numbers like currency ($xxx.xx), I wrote a class using [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) to validate the pattern and the size of characters, but what I can not achieve is that the user can type more than one dot.

Here is an example of my code:

```
private class LimitCharactersFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    private int limit;
    private Pattern regex = Pattern.compile( "\\d*(\\.\\d{0,2})?");
    private Matcher matcher;

    public LimitCharactersFilter(int limit) {           
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr)
            throws BadLocationException {
        String fullText = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()) + string;
        matcher = regex.matcher(fullText);
        if((fullText.length()) <= limit && matcher.matches()){
            fb.insertString(offset, string, attr);
        }else{
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
            throws BadLocationException {
        String fullText = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()) + text;
        matcher = regex.matcher(fullText);
        matcher = regex.matcher(text);
        if((fullText.length()) <= limit && matcher.matches()){
            fb.replace(offset,length, text, attrs);
        }else{
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a picture of how the interface looks:
[image: Interface Screenshot]

Validate the limit of characters works great, but I want to restrict the user to enter more than two digits if there's already a dot.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Try `\\d*\\.?\\d{0,2}`, but it will be only good for live input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much!, this worked pretty well, and yes, I didn't explained it too well, but I wanted it to be for live input, and your solution worked great for me.

Comment: The correct way to make a text field that allows currency as input is with `new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow the dot to be entered when typing a float number, you can use

```
\\d*\\.?\\d{0,2}
```

Note that here,

- `\\d*` - zero or more digits
- `\\.?` - one or zero dots
- `\\d+` - one or more digits

Please also consider using VGR's suggestion:

```
new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance());
```

This will create a text field that allows currency as input.